# What is it called when we speak of foods using brand names?

Tags: single-word-requests, food, cultural-phrases

I am wondering about the phenomenon of brand names being commonly used to describe certain foods.

For example, I recently heard the phrase **“to eat cheetos“**.

Other examples could be **to eat/drink...**

- smarties
- kellogg's
- pepsi
- ...

Is there a word that describes this phenomenon of using brand names when referring to certain foods or drinks?

An example for one way of using it:

> “I am sick of people who are constantly [word that describes the phenomenon of using brand names]!“

Comment: A British speaker, I presume. I don't think the brand *Smarties* exist in the US, its nearest equivalent is called *Skittles* if memory serves me correctly. *Kellog's* doesn't really work because they sell several different cereals, but I would understand immediately what is meant. I think it's kind of cute, it might get annoying if everyone spoke this way, but I don't think it's that widespread. Are you a BrEng speaker?

Comment: It's called "speaking".  Just as if you say "I saw Jim yesterday."

Comment: @Mari-LouA: No, I am not a BrEng speaker. I am a non-native speaker. I am also not specifically focusing on the brands I listet as examples, but brands in general. I don't really know where which brands are popular (“cheetos“ , for example, is totally unknown where I live, which is in Germany. I can't even think of a brand similar to cheetos here in Germany, either. Germans would just say “Ich esse (Käse)flips/Chips/...“. At least when it comes to snacks, I can't think of a brand. Of course, there are plenty of other brands).

Comment: OK perhaps I misunderstood your question, you're not referring to someone who uses the brand name in place of the food term, e.g I drank some soda/pop vs I drank a Pepsi. It's normal to say what you had to eat or drink during the day especially where snack foods are concerned. *"We went out for a MacDonald's"*, *"He only had some Pringles for lunch"*, and I could tell a friend *"I ordered a cup of Lady/Earl Grey (tea) at ____"*. I don't think it odd at all. P.S Brand names should always be capitalised.

Comment: Maybe my question is a bit misleading or not formulated clear enough, sorry for that! I also don't think it is odd, not at all, but I am simply wondering whether there is a name for it as almost everything gets named and defined. Maybe this is one of the phenomenons that are not named yet? And thank you, I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: It's a form of name-dropping. But people are as free to refer to particular brands as they are to speak more generically. If they had a Kit Kat, or don't like Kit Kats, why can't they say so? // Perhaps you mean _inaccurately_ using a brand name as a substitute for a generic term (I hoovered instead of I vacced, when you have a Dyson). This is known as genericisation, and has been covered here before.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Thank you, I think that helps. Maybe my thoughts on this question rather belong on the philosophy site ;) Could you link the question you have in mind?

Comment: The phrase **brand-dropping** appears to have some currency, but it would usually be considered a form of boasting (about having or being able to afford the big name brands), so I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Actually I think Smarties are much more like chocolate-only M&Ms

Comment: @Au101 Right you are, Skittles (which were first produced in the UK) are fruit flavoured sweets, aka jelly beans,  while British [Smarties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarties) are practically the same as sugar-coated "M&Ms".

Comment: ... and pre-dated them by some 4 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*“I am sick of people who are constantly genericizing trademarks!“*

> A generic trademark, also known as a genericized trademark or proprietary eponym, is a trademark or brand name that, due to its popularity and/or significance, has become the generic name for, or synonymous with, a general class of product or service, usually against the intentions of the trademark's holder. [...]
>   A trademark is said to become **genericized** when it begins as a distinctive product identifier but changes in meaning to become generic.
>
> Thermos,[4] Kleenex, Dumpster and Realtor are examples of trademarks that have become genericized in the US.
>   - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark

Comment: @Clare your comment brings to my mind ... "The Lord gave, and the Lord hath taken away;"

Comment: Sorry............

Comment: @Clare no worries; I hadn't noticed the close vote originally, but I agree it's a duplicate so ... will vote accordingly!

Answer (score -3):

*Product-place* or *support product-placement*.

The person doing what you describe might be doing it only because the brand name is what occurs to them, to represent the generic thing.  Or they might be doing it as a kind of promotion, or intentional *product placement*.  Or they might be doing it because they are unconsciously repeating what they've heard or seen in some commercial *product placement*.

See [Product placement, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_placement).

(For a good example of food-product placement, check out season 5 of *Orange is the New Black*, where both *Cheetos* and *Takis* are shown and referred to constantly in the last few episodes.)

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I upvoted to reverse the down-vote.  This is, of course, the point: that we use brand names because advertisers are successful; if they're too successful, the brand name becomes a generic.

Comment: “The person doing what you describe might be doing it only because the brand name is what occurs to them, to represent the generic thing.“ I think that comes pretty close. Maybe we could call it something like 'generic and subconscious product placement'?

Comment: But this term doesn't apply when the product is not being "promoted", but rather it's just people saying what they had for lunch or whatever.

Comment: @HotLicks: Agreed: it does not apply consciously in such cases. But even then it generally has the effect of promoting the product. Whether the OP wants to consider this use as product-placement or not is a question. Personally, I'd opt for coining *product-place* as a verb, with a healthily negative (for me) connotation. And I'd use it to point out to someone that by using a brand name they are, in effect, promoting that brand to some degree. I wouldn't use it for the occasional reference, but I might call out repetitive reference as (probably unintentional) product placement.